# Scanf to filter input

Tags: c, scanf

My question is pretty simple i want to use `scanf` to filter input and put every word in an `array of string (array char 2d)`

I tried with `fgetc()` but it's hard at least for me to get every word.

```
data.txt
```

```
add $t3,$s3,$s5
sh $v0,8($s0)
```

expected result :

```
add 
$t3
$s3
$s5   
sh
$v0
8
$s0
```

let's assume we need an array of 10x10 :

```
char test [10][10];

strcpy(test[0],"add");
...
... // looping until the last input
...
strcpy(test[7],$s0);
```

--EDIT--

I tried this code that process just one line for testing:

```
    char test[10][10]
    char c;
    unsigned int i = 0 , j = 0;
    FILE *fp = fopen("./data.txt", "rb");

    while((c=fgetc(fp)) != EOF )
            {     
                if (c == ' ' || c == '(' || c == ')' ){

                }else if( c == '$' || (c == ',')){
                    i++;
                    j = 0;
                    test[i][j]=c;
                    j++;

                }else if(c == '\n'){
                    i = 0;
                    j = 0;
                    break;
                }else{
                    test[i][j]= c;
                    j++;
                }
            }
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you tried `fgets` + `sscanf`?  Your buffer sizes are very small; what if a word is 10 characters long?

Comment: What code have you tried until now?

Comment: @CacahueteFrito i updated what i tried. i'm really uneasy on this type of input that's why i'm asking for a way to do it. And the maximum word length is 7 i can assure there is no more 7.

Comment: I don't understand the difference between `' '` and `','`. Or the similarity between `','` and `'$'`; given your desired output

Comment: lets take `add $t0,$s3,$s4`  -> 1. if there is a space ignore it, -> 2. `$` and `,` mark the begining of a new word. -> 3. i want to keep `$` in the output not the `,` , i know my code is wrong that's why  i ask for somthing that give me the correct output. @CacahueteFrito

Comment: `sh $v0,8($s0)` here, what is the meaning of the parentheses?

Comment: same logic `8` is a word and `$s0` is a word. to simplify i want the word between the parentheses. @CacahueteFrito

Comment: Then, try playing with this: `fgets` to read lines, and `sscanf(" %9[^,$()]", str);` to read every word

Comment: Can you help me with a piece of code, i'm totally lost. @CacahueteFrito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm late but still if you need not use a `scanf()` family function for this, you could use [`strtok()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok).

Do something like

```
FILE *fin = fopen("input.txt", "r");
if(fin==NULL)
{
    return -1;
}
char buff[50];
while(fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fin)!=NULL)
{
    for(char *ptr=strtok(buff, " (),\n"); ptr!=NULL; ptr=strtok(NULL, " (),\n"))
    {
        printf("%s\n", ptr);
    }
}
```

The second argument of `strtok()` is a string of characters each of which is a delimiter for the tokens that we wish to extract.

For the given input, output would be

```
add
$t3
$s3
$s5
sh
$v0
8
$s0
```

Answer (score 1):

```c
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>


#define ARRAY_SIZE(arr)     (sizeof(arr) / sizeof((arr)[0]))
#define ARRAY_SSIZE(arr)    ((ptrdiff_t)ARRAY_SIZE(arr))


int     main    (void)
{
        FILE        *fp;
        char        buff[BUFSIZ];
        char        *s;
        ptrdiff_t   len;
        char        str[10][10][10];
        int         n;

        fp = fopen("./data.txt", "r");

        memset(str, 0, sizeof(str));

        for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SSIZE(str); i++) {
                if (!fgets(buff, sizeof(buff), fp))
                        break;

                len = strlen(buff);
                s   = buff;
                for (ptrdiff_t j = 0; ((s - buff) < len) &&
                                (j < ARRAY_SSIZE(str[0])); s += n+1, j++) {
                        n   = 0;
                        if (sscanf(s, " %9[^ ,()\n]%n", str[i][j], &n) == EOF)
                                break;
                }
        }

        for (ptrdiff_t i = 0; i < ARRAY_SSIZE(str); i++) {
                for (ptrdiff_t j = 0; j < ARRAY_SSIZE(str[0]); j++) {
                        if (str[i][j][0])
                                printf("%s\n", str[i][j]);
                }
        }

        return  0;
}
```

I separated each line so that you can play with them separately if you need it.

This is the most important line:

```
                    if (sscanf(s, " %9[^ ,()\n]%n", str[i][j], &n) == EOF)
                            break;
```

it reads from a string `s`, `" %9[^ ,()\n]"` discards any whitespace and accepts an array of `char`s until the first of the following characters are found: `" ,()\n"` or until it reaches the maximum length of 9 (9 + `'\0'` = 10).  the string is stored in `str[i][j]`;  after that, `"%n"` stores in `n` the number of characters consumed in the buffer, so that you can update the `char *` to point just after the next unread character (actually one after that one, because we know that the first unread character will be a comma or something like that so it will be a character we don't want.  That job (updating the pointer) is done in this line:

```
            for (ptrdiff_t j = 0; ((s - buff) < len) &&
                            (j < ARRAY_SSIZE(str[0])); s += n+1, j++) {
```